# How to verify if MFA delete is on or not on a list of bucket using Python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multi-factor-authentication

Hello I have a list of buckets that I would like to verify if those buckets have mfa enabled or not using python script, but I don't have much knowledge in python. Can anyone please help me. The process is to check the buckets then print if mfa is enabled or else print it's disabled. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import boto3

buckets = ['...']

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

for b in buckets:
    resp = s3.get_bucket_versioning(Bucket=b)
    if mfa:=resp.get('MFADelete'):
        print(f"{b}: MFA delete is {mfa}")
    else:
        print(f"{b}: MFA delete is never configured")
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it seems to be working. Btw can i use the same process to check if  s3-bucket-logging-enabled is enabled or not?. thankyou.

Comment: @FLixYuu Yes, use the `get_bucket_logging` api instead.